# Why does mt_rand(1, PHP_INT_MAX) always return an odd number

Tags: php, random

I've just come across an [interesting question](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9941364) from ComputerGuru on Hacker News and no comment seems to give a convincing answer.

Why does `mt_rand(1, PHP_INT_MAX)` always return an odd number?

I am not the author of the original question.

http://3v4l.org/dMbat

```
for ($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
{
    echo mt_rand(1, PHP_INT_MAX)."\n";
}
```

output:

```
8571620074060775425
7401021871338029057
4351677773593444353
1801559362708176897
7848614552286527489
...
```

Comment: Probably related to this, taken from [the PHP manual page for mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php): *Caution: The distribution of mt_rand() return values is biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32. This is because if max is greater than the value returned by mt_getrandmax(), the output of the random number generator must be scaled up.*

Comment: Because PHP_INT_MAX > mt_getrandmax(), [more details](https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/3eaw98/mt_rand1_php_int_max_only_generates_odd_numbers/ctdhxha).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PHP_INT_MAX` here is 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (64-bit signed int max).

However, `mt_rand()` doesn't handle values this large. The Mersenne twister internally generates 32-bit words, and PHP's `mt_getrandmax()` is only 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (it throws away the highest bit).

To generate a value in your requested `min` to `max` range, `mt_rand` first gets the 0 to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 random number, then scales it using this formula:

```
x = ((x / (mt_getrandmax() + 1)) * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

(See the source of [rand.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c) and [php_rand.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_rand.h).)

Basically it blindly scales the internally generated number to fit the overlarge range, without even raising a warning. Multiplying to fit the overlarge range generates a lot of zeroes in the low bits, then adding `min` (which is 1) makes the result odd.

The problem is more dramatic in hexadecimal, where you can see that the low 32 bits of each number are *completely* non-random:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    printf("%016x\n", mt_rand(1, PHP_INT_MAX));
}
```

Output:

```
41e0449b00000001
53d33d7c00000001
6ec8855700000001
234140e000000001
13a4581900000001
77547beb00000001
35a0660a00000001
0d0cd44200000001
...
```

There is a note [in the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) that tries to warn about this, although it understates the problem:

> The distribution of `mt_rand()` return values is biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when `max` is beyond 2<sup>32</sup>. This is because if `max` is greater than the value returned by `mt_getrandmax()`, the output of the random number generator must be scaled up.

(It says it's biased towards even numbers, but that's only true when `min` is even.)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. Odd that PHP doesn't throw an error/exception if you pass it a value rather than `mt_getrandmax()`.